# compare arrays with repetitive elements and add the elements not present to the respective arrays including the repetitive elements

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am working on a program where we compare two strings and add the characters that are not present in one string to the other string and vice versa.
For example: String 1- aabccd
             String 2- acccdd
The output should be- Characters to be added to String 1- cd
                      Characters to be added to String 2- ab
I am able to achieve it when the characters are not repeating,
For example: String 1- mango
             String 2- anglo
The output is- Characters to be added to String 1- l
               Characters to be added to String 2- m 
but could not get it when the characters are repeating.

Here is the code that I have written-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String S1, S2;

        System.out.println("Enter String 1: ");
        S1 = user_input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter String 2: ");
        S2 = user_input.next();

        user_input.close();

        char[] S1Array = S1.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        char[] S2Array = S2.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        charAddition(S1Array, S2Array);
        charAdditionReverse(S2Array,S1Array);
}
private static void charAddition(char[] n, char[] S1Array) {
for (char n1 : n) {
            if (!isPresent(n1, S1Array)) {
                System.out.println("character to be added to S2Array
is: " + n1);
            }
        }
}
private static void charAdditionReverse(char[] n, char[] S1Array) {
for (char n1 : n) {
            if (!isPresent(n1, S1Array)) {
                System.out.println("character to be added to S1Array
is: " + n1);


            }
        }
}


    private static boolean isPresent(char n, char[] S1Array) {
        for (char i : S1Array) {
            if (n == i) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String S1, S2;

        System.out.println("Enter String 1: ");
        S1 = user_input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter String 2: ");
        S2 = user_input.next();

        user_input.close();

        char[] S1Array = S1.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        char[] S2Array = S2.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        charAddition(S1Array, S2Array,false);
        charAddition(S2Array,S1Array,true);
    }
    private static void charAddition(char[] n, char[] S1Array,boolean isreverse) 
    {

        List<char[]> asList = Arrays.asList(S1Array); // because this DOES compile.

        List<Character> wordlist = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (char c : S1Array) {
            wordlist.add(c);
        }

        for (char n1 : n) 
        {
            if (!isPresent(n1, wordlist)) 
            {
                if(!isreverse)
                {
                    System.out.println("character to be added to S2Arrayis: " + n1);

                }else
                {
                    System.out.println("character to be added to S1Arrayis: " + n1);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private static boolean isPresent(char n, List<Character> S1Array) 
    {
        boolean flag ;
        for (Iterator<Character> it = S1Array.iterator(); it.hasNext();) 
        {
            char i = it.next();
            if (n == i) 
            {
                it.remove();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

To solve above problem, you have to check how many times a specific character repeats. that's why I created new array list from array passed ArrayList to the function and removed the elements which are already matched. I have changed 2 function into one as i felt it is better way to write code.

Comment: and it works perfectly for your example of "aabccd" and "acccdd" :)

Comment: Please use proper formatting: **1)** Use proper indentation; **2)** Follow the Java Naming Conventions – variable names should start with lowercase and don't contain underscores.

Comment: please just give a minute, I do it all.. sorry, my mistake

Comment: I cant change the variable names he already used, otherwise he will get confused you know.. although i checked names for all variables i created for answer :)

Comment: welcome.. :)  ...  select as answer if you think it is :)

Answer (score 0):

A whole different approach:

```
void disjoint(String s1, String s2) {
    // Convert two strings to character lists
    List<Character> chars1 = s1.chars()
        .mapToObj(t -> (char) t)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Character> chars2 = s2.chars()
        .mapToObj(t -> (char) t)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Make a list of elements we are going to remove from chars1
    List<Character> removedElements = new ArrayList<>();
    chars1.forEach(t -> {
        // Try to remove the current character from chars2, and if it has
        // successfully been removed, add it to our removedElements list
        if (chars2.remove(t)) {
            removedElements.add(t);
        }
    });
    // At last remove each removed element from chars2 also from chars1
    removedElements.forEach(chars1::remove);

    System.out.println(chars1);
    System.out.println(chars2);

}
```